# Apache+PHP. Memory leak. Strange

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, web-server

I have CentOS 5 installed on my server. I'm in VPS server.

I have site where I have constant online ~150. First look on site looks OK. But when I go through links, sometimes I receive Out of memory PHP error.
It looks like this

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 36962304) (tried to allocate 7680 bytes) in /home/armtimes/public_html/sites/all/modules/cck/modules/fieldgroup/fieldgroup.install on line 100
```

And always, not allocated memory is very small.

In average I have 30% CPU load, 25% RAM load. So I think here is not a physical memory problem.

I have no any error log in apache's log files. Nothing connected with this.

Past I have not met with this on my server and the problem appeared itself.

Besides this I'm receiving some server errors on mail.

```
cpsrvd failed @ Fri Sep 24 16:45:20 2010. A restart was attempted automagically.
Service Check Method:  [tcp connect]

Failure Reason: Unable to connect to port 2086
```

Same for tailwatchd.

Support tried, and can't help me...

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate more memory.  When doing certain things, Drupal takes quite a bit of memory.  Most of the sites we run, we set the memory to 96MB (for image handling reasons).  This should likely clear it up for you.

Comment: My limit is set to 1000MB

Comment: No, no its not.  You may *think* it is, but its set at about 36MB.

I'd advise checking to make sure that settings.php and .htaccess do not have a setting that is overriding the one in php.ini

If neither of those show that, then check the report section on Drupal and see how much memory it shows as being available.

Comment: Every time that value is different. Allocated memory.

Comment: I aggree. It looks like a programming thing from this drupal module. I guess that php is using a lot of memory in a loop, or a big array with big objects. You can also contact the drupal module creator and tell him about problem. They could set a higher limit locally if they need more memory and later restore it to the initial value, or they can optimize the code.

Answer (score 0):

The value that it shows when you hit the error will be different depending on what caused it.

Here, toss me a screenshot like this:

[image]

This is available at admin/reports/status

Comment: So my PHP memory limit is set to 1500M... hmm.